# Dealing with messy JSON API and UTF-8 encoding problems

Tags: python, json, unicode

I am using an API that returns a JSON object that has `"encoded_polyline"` fields that tend to result in errors like this one:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udb6e' in position 2: surrogates not allowed

Since the offending fields don't offer useful data, I decided the best would be to get rid of the fields causing these errors. However, these fields are sometimes stored at the top level of the JSON object but also sometimes stored within an array at either:

- `jsonobject["points"]["points"]`
- `jsonobject["laps"]["metric"]`
- `jsonobject["laps"]["imperial"]`

I think I've finally got something working to hunt down all these fields and delete them, but I have a feeling this could be done much more cleanly.

```
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':UA})
jsonobject = r.json()
if 'laps' in jsonobject and jsonobject['laps'] is not None:
    if 'imperial' in jsonobject['laps']:
        laps_array = jsonobject['laps']['imperial']
        type = 'imperial'
    if 'metric' in jsonobject['laps']:
        laps_array = jsonobject['laps']['metric']
        type = 'metric'
    if laps_array is not None:
        jsonobject['laps_correct'] = dict()
        jsonobject['laps_correct'][type] = list()
        for document in laps_array:
            #sometimes these document objects turn out to be dicts
            #and sometimes they turn out to be strings
            #even though JSON output is always the same
            #is there a better way to deal with this?
            if document.__class__.__name__ == "dict":
                document2 = document
            else:
                document2 = json.loads(document)
            if 'small_encoded_polyline' in document2 and document2['small_encoded_polyline'] is not None:
                del document2['small_encoded_polyline']
                document = document2
                #I thought this line above would modify the original
                #jsonobject since document is a dictionary so I should
                #be working with a pointer to the original object
                #but inspection of jsonobject reveals this not to be the case
                jsonobject['laps_correct'][type].append(document2)
        del jsonobject['laps']
        jsonobject['laps'] = jsonobject.pop('laps_correct')

# this can't be an elif because sometimes json objects 
# have both "points" and "laps"
if 'points' in jsonobject and jsonobject['points'] is not None:
    if 'points' in jsonobject['points']:
        laps_array = jsonobject['points']['points']
        jsonobject['points_correct'] = dict()
        jsonobject['points_correct']['points'] = list()
        if laps_array is not None:
            for document in laps_array:
                if document.__class__.__name__ == "dict":
                    document2 = document
                else:
                    document2 = json.loads(document)
                    if 'small_encoded_polyline' in document2 and document2['small_encoded_polyline'] is not None:
                        del document2['small_encoded_polyline']
                        document = document2
                        jsonobject['points_correct']['points'].append(document2)
        del jsonobject['points']
        jsonobject['points'] = jsonobject.pop('points_correct')

if 'small_encoded_polyline' in jsonobject and jsonobject['small_encoded_polyline'] is not None:
    del jsonobject['small_encoded_polyline']
```

My two biggest worries/questions are:

1. How can I deal with variables that are sometimes typed as dicts and sometimes as strings even though the JSON format appears identical in both cases?
2. Is it really necessary to delete original key and replace it rather than updating dicts from the original key? This seems slow and clunky.

Comment: Is it not possible with the API you're using to manually fix up the encoding before parsing it as JSON? (Like in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116089/surrogateescape-cannot-escape-certain-characters); admittedly I'm not sure if that is exactly your problem.)

Comment: Where does `r` come from? I suspect that that is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @200_success r is a requests object (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: What does `r.headers['content-type']` say?

Comment: @200_success type is: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1

Comment: Woah. Do you have control over the server-side code?

Comment: @200_success No not at all. And they don't offer much guidance.

Comment: @ferada I read over that SO post, but I'm not sure how it fixes the problem. Seems like the accepted answer in particular is saying this is the proper behavior and the best is to catch an error. But since I still want the data catching the error and just moving on to the next record is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. I don't see why `del jsonobject[...]` would be necessary before
   reassigning that key.  Also, the test in the last two lines could
   also be simplified to something like
   `jsonobject.pop('small_encoded_polyline', None)` if you don't care
   about that key, no?

Also:

- Everything could use more error checking.  That is, check expected
  types and values instead of falling through the `if`s (`'imperial'`,
  `'metric'`, what happens if it's neither, or both?).
- Unless you really prefer `list` and `dict`, it's better to use the
  literal syntax `[]` and `{}` (the names could be shadowed by some
  definition).
- The type check for `dict`s can be better, i.e.
  `isinstance(foo, dict)`; if you really want *only* `dict`, then it's
  still better to use `type(foo) is dict` instead of comparing strings.
  I'd also move that whole `if/else` into a function,
  e.g. `maybe_load_json` or so.
- The value of `document` after the assignments isn't used anywhere, so
  it's safe to remove, though I'd rather use that variable again instead
  of introducing `document2`.
- The second branch with `'small_encoded_polyline'` seems to have the
  wrong level of indentation?  At least it's different from the first
  one in that it's only run if the document wasn't a `dict`.  Assuming
  that it's safe to run anyway I'll change that in the code below.
- The pattern `if foo in json and json[foo] is not None:` could be easier
  be achieved with `if json.get(foo) is not None:` as the return value
  there defaults to `None`.
- I'm not particularly fond of the habit to reuse input data like with
  `'points_correct'` done here.  It would be cleaner just to have a list
  `points_correct` and assign that to a `jsonobject` key (and you know,
  possibly put the calculation into a separate function as well).

I might have messed up some of the logic now, but I hope you get the
idea:

```
def maybe_load_json(document):
    if isinstance(document, dict):
        return document
    return json.loads(document)


def cleaned_small_encoded_polylines(documents):
    result = []
    for document in documents:
        #sometimes these document objects turn out to be dicts
        #and sometimes they turn out to be strings
        #even though JSON output is always the same
        #is there a better way to deal with this?
        document = maybe_load_json(document)
        if document.get('small_encoded_polyline') is not None:
            del document['small_encoded_polyline']
            #I thought this line above would modify the original
            #jsonobject since document is a dictionary so I should
            #be working with a pointer to the original object
            #but inspection of jsonobject reveals this not to be the case
            result.append(document)
    return result

...

    r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':UA})
    jsonobject = r.json()
    if jsonobject.get('laps') is not None:
        if 'imperial' in jsonobject['laps']:
            laps_array = jsonobject['laps']['imperial']
            type = 'imperial'
        if 'metric' in jsonobject['laps']:
            laps_array = jsonobject['laps']['metric']
            type = 'metric'
        if laps_array is not None:
            jsonobject['laps'][type] = cleaned_small_encoded_polylines(laps_array)

    # this can't be an elif because sometimes json objects
    # have both "points" and "laps"
    if jsonobject.get('points') is not None:
        if 'points' in jsonobject['points']:
            points_correct = []
            laps_array = jsonobject['points']['points']
            if laps_array is not None:
                jsonobject['points']['points'] = cleaned_small_encoded_polylines(laps_array)

    jsonobject.pop('small_encoded_polyline', None)
```

Comment: Agreed on both points.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expanded answer. I agree with most of what you say, but this comment confused me: Unless you really prefer list and dict, it's better to use the literal syntax (fast, can't override it). I actually don't know what you mean by that even after looking at your modifications to the code.

Comment: @sunny Ah sorry, I mean use `[]` and `{}` instead of `list()` and `dict()` to create an empty list and dictionary.

Comment: many thanks, so this is good for me to learn the lingo.